# Micronaut endpoint responding with 401

Tags: java, rest, micronaut, http-status-code-401

I have a REST endpoint(POST) in my Micronaut microservice. The endpoint is intended to work without any authentication. However, testing the endpoint I cannot reach it.

I tried several annotations on the endpoint. But that does not seem to do the trick. Seems like I am missing something obvious here. Could you please advise any ideas?

This is my controller:

```
    @Controller("/v1/connect")
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
public class ConnectController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectController.class);
    
    @Inject
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Post("/activation")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @PermitAll
    public SuccessResponse sendActivationEmail(ActivationRequest activationRequest) throws MessagingException {
        LOG.info(String.format("Send activation mail for <email: %s>", activationRequest.getRecipientEmail()));
        emailService.SendActivationEmail(activationRequest.getRecipientEmail(), activationRequest.getActivationLink());
        return new SuccessResponse(true);
    }
}
```

ActivationRequest which is basically the payload:

```
public class ActivationRequest {

private String recipientEmail;
private String activationLink;

public ActivationRequest() {
}

public String getRecipientEmail() {
    return recipientEmail;
}

public void setRecipientEmail(String recipientEmail) {
    this.recipientEmail = recipientEmail;
}

public String getActivationLink() {
    return activationLink;
}

public void setActivationLink(String activationLink) {
    this.activationLink = activationLink;
}
```

}

Here is how I call the endpoit:

[image]
[image]

Application.yml

```
    micronaut:
  application:
    name: hdsEmailMicroservice
  server:
    port: 4001
  security:
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /swagger/**
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /swagger-ui/**
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
  router:
    static-resources:
      swagger:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger
        mapping: /swagger/**
      swagger-ui:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui
        mapping: /swagger-ui/**
netty:
  default:
    allocator:
      max-order: 3

logger:
  fullStackTrace: true
```

Comment: Are you assigning a value to `micronaut.security.intercept-url-map` anywhere (`application.yml`, distributed config server, OS env variables, etc...)?

Comment: Is your `emailService.SendActivationEmail`(or anything that it calls) method marked with security restrictions?

Comment: No email service isn't marked with any security restrictions. And I added application.yml to my question....

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.  If you can share a sample app that demonstrates the issue I would be happy to look into it.  If you believe what you are seeing is a bug in the framework, please file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/issues and we will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code without `EmailService`. So my code looks like this:

```
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces;
import io.micronaut.security.annotation.Secured;
import io.micronaut.security.rules.SecurityRule;
import jakarta.annotation.security.PermitAll;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Controller("/v1/connect")
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
public class ConnectController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectController.class);

    @Post("/activation")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @PermitAll
    public void sendActivationEmail(ActivationRequest activationRequest) {
        LOG.info(String.format("Send activation mail for <email: %s>", activationRequest.getRecipientEmail()));
    }
}
```

```
public class ActivationRequest {

    private String recipientEmail;
    private String activationLink;

    public ActivationRequest() {
    }

    public String getRecipientEmail() {
        return recipientEmail;
    }

    public void setRecipientEmail(String recipientEmail) {
        this.recipientEmail = recipientEmail;
    }

    public String getActivationLink() {
        return activationLink;
    }

    public void setActivationLink(String activationLink) {
        this.activationLink = activationLink;
    }

}
```

There wasn't any error and I received 200. Maybe your `EmailService` have been throwing something?

And your response time is strange. Why is it ~400ms?
Do you sure you use the right port? The default port is 8080. Maybe you did something in application.yml which affected to the security?